# Select all columns with Mix,Max functions in where condition without group by in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to select all the columns from single table like below:

```
select name,id,salary 
from tbl_name 
where max(age) <> mix(age);
```

I don't want to use any group by/order by.

Please help me.

Comment: Huh?  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would help.  Why would you expect the minimum and maximum ages *for the entire table* to be the same?

Comment: What about your query doesn't work? Be more specific.

Comment: I am getting error like aggregation max,min can't be used in where condition like that

Comment: You _need_ a `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hive `window functions` if you don't want to use `group by/order by`. You can check same query below & you may change this as per your use case.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        NAME,
        ID,
        SALARY,
        AGE,
        MAX(AGE) OVER() AS MAX_AGE,
        MIN(AGE) OVER() AS MIN_AGE 
    FROM TBL_NAME
) TBL 
WHERE TBL.MAX_AGE <> TBL.MIN_AGE;
```